# Is a software request appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking for software to read and write "structured" mathematics. Would such a request be appropriate for the Tex page?

Comment: Thumbs up for asking here before posting the question!

Comment: This question _could_ be on-topic on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com). And [mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a software that could be used for that.

Comment: Ask it on main explaining the details. It would be nice something like that in beamer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your question is about how to write such mathematics with (La)TeX or if it is possible in your requested way at all, then the question would be on-topic, but should be well phrased nevertheless.

If you are looking for some other software, or looking for people to program one for you, then the question would be off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that such tweaks in LaTeX output in PDFs are possible, so it can be on-topic here. However, I think that LaTeX is not ready for such document design, and you might somehow better do with MathJaX. And dispite MathJaX's syntax is similar to LaTeX's, it is the only common point and questions about it are off-topic.

I do not discourage you from asking, as long as it's about LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, MathJaX works great!